# Across with multiple arguments

Tags: r, across

This can be a very dumb question regarding application of 'across' function with multiple columns and different funs applied to each. For eg, below is an example from 'iris' data where column names starting with 'Sepal' are averaged. What if I along with this I want to take median of columns starting with 'Petal'. How can I give the two different column types and funs in same summarise?

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple `across` statements in one `summarise`/`mutate` :

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean), 
            across(starts_with("Petal"), median))

#  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#* <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 setosa             5.01        3.43         1.5          0.2
#2 versicolor         5.94        2.77         4.35         1.3
#3 virginica          6.59        2.97         5.55         2
```

Comment: Can we also change the name of output cols simultaneously?

Comment: Yes we can handle that using `.names`. `across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean, .names = '{col}_mean')`